# Is there a way to stay for more than 90 days under the US Visa Waiver Program?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program

My sister will be in USA for 100 days with Visa Waiver.  Is there a way that she can travel to another country and enter the USA again, so as not to contravene the 90 day limit of Visa Waiver?

Answer (score 41):

Your sister cannot stay legally in the US more than 90 days with the visa waiver program. Nor can she go to Canada, Mexico or some nearby islands as the time spent there will be included in the 90 days, specifically to address the visa-run problem. Even if she flies to, say, Europe, and returns quickly she risks refusal at the border.

If she wants to stay in the US legally for more than 90 days she should apply for a B1/B2 visa which will allow her up to six months.

Comment: It's actually *at least 6 months* in most cases: even if a B-1/B-2 visa holder says they need only 100 days, they will usually be admitted for 6 months. In addition, it is possible to file for an extension from within the US, while this is not possible for VWP visitors.

Comment: @Brian But is it possible to apply for a B1/B2 visa if you are already in the USA with the VWP?

Comment: @undefined You can submit a visa application while you are in the US, but you'll have to appear at a consulate (outside the US) in order to be interviewed and have the visa issued in your passport.

Comment: @undefined well, OP was saying that travel to another country was already considered, so applying in the USA is not necessary here.